# How to call java file and it's function and parse them from groovy file of Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

i want to access Hashmap of my java file from groovy script and parse it.

Comment: Your question is way unclear.  Please check faq https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve it

Comment: If you are a beginner https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/guide-integrating.html is _unlikely_ place to start

Comment: https://objectcomputing.com/resources/publications/sett/february-2004-groovy-scripting-for-java#:~:text=Groovy%20scripts%20can%20use%20any,classes)%20is%20not%20supported%20yet.

Comment: None of the link,help me much, 

I want to access the Hashmap of my java file from the groovy script and parse it.

Comment: Please add your java code and groovy code.